# Is there a way to update/delete picklist values more easily?

Tags: picklist

I find that updating picklist values or deleting them is tedious. For example, suppose you have to change 10 values for a custom picklist field. You have to click on edit link near each value, and then click save.  Same thing for deletion.

My question is: is there another way to do this? I don't believe Salesforce provides an out-of-the-box tool for this, but do you know a custom application that offers a better management of picklist values? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the metadata API from apex to edit the picklist values.

Comment: Have a look at Eclipse & MavensMate, I know that the former makes it easier to edit picklist values but neither tool is particularly easy to set up & you need to be careful when deploying the changes. There may be a more user friendly app.

Comment: Yeah Mavensamte does the job. But still, it is not really convenient. Thanks anyway!